CommandButton in VB6
Good evening, in my project in vb6, I have 1 Product form, in it I have 2 command buttons, cmdNew and cmdSaves, cmdSaves is set to Enabled = False, how do I ensure that when I click on cmdNew it (cmdSaves) is set to enabled = True?
Below is my current code that doesn't work:
Private Sub cmdNew_Click()
    Me.cmdSalvar.Enabled = True
End Sub

I also tried to do a select case looking for the captions but it didn't work.
I also tried to create functions that did this, and that were called when clicking cmdNew, but it didn't work either.

Have you tried debugging? Set a breakpoint in the cmdNew_Click event; does the breakpoint even get hit? Also: did you check this question?

Also: Why are you (still) doing VB6 in 2024? Mainstream support for VB6 ended on March 31, 2005, and Extended support ended in March 2008. The final release was 26(!) years ago. You really should've moved to VB.Net at the very least by now.

As @RobIII said, try setting a breakpoint on the first statement of the cmdNew_Click() button event handler, and make sure it's actually being executed.  Your code looks too simple not to work, so it's likely to be something dumb like a misspelling.  (You are using Option Explicit I hope...)
Incidentally, as long as you're on the same form, you don't need the "Me." specifier; normally I don't disagree with explicitly specifying implicit items for clarity, but this particular one is so common that I find it's unnecessary clutter.  It shouldn't have broken anything, though.

What is the button's name? "cmdSaves" as your text states or "cmdSalvar" that your code suggests?
